# Adjective endings after a noun of measurement

Tags: grammar, genitive, dative

I was looking through my grammar book and I came across this sentence:

> Mit einer Tasse heißem Tee

I don't understand why *heiß* has an m at the end. I would have thought it would be:

> Mit einer Tasse heissen Tees

Answer (score 5):

Both examples are correct. The second one is considered elevated or refined language.

Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007:

> Substantivierte Adjektive und Partizipien nach Mengenangaben stehen gewöhnlich im Genitiv:
>   (…)
>   Dagegen weisen singularische Substantive nach Mengen- und Maßangaben heute gewöhnlich denselben Kasus wie diese auf (= appositionelles Verhältnis):
>   (…)
>   Der früher übliche Genitiv wird nur noch vereinzelt bei solchen Substantiven im Singular verwendet, die durch ein Adjektiv näher bestimmt sind; der Genitiv gilt als gehoben oder sogar gespreizt:
>   (…) bei einer Tasse *Kaffee / duftendem Kaffee /* (geh.:) *duftenden Kaffees;* (…)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Duden knows what he says. But I would avoid "eine Tasse heißen Tees".
That reminds me too much of the language of Schiller, two hundred years ago. And I would also avoid "eine Tasse heißem Tee". That sounds very awkward to me.

I would simply say "Ich möchte einen heißen Tee", to avoid the problem with adjective + noun after a noun describing quantity.

But I admit that some such structures as "eine Flasche guten Weins" are still common.

Comment: If you simply leave out _mit_, "eine Tasse heißen Tee" sounds perfectly natural to me.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert, however *mit* is a preposition that always requires the dative. The sentence in the textbook is correct:

> Mit heiße**m** Tee

Comment: The main point of the question is that it’s not *heißer Tee* but *eine Tasse* to which *mit* refers. Thus your answer is hardly helpful for this question.