# ein Glas warmer Milch

Tags: difference

Which is standard German? "Ich trinke ein Glas warmer Milch" (genitive) or "Ich trinke ein Glas warme Milch" (accusative); a Google search suggests that the second choice is more frequent, but I'm not sure that I understand completely why. Vielen Dank.

Comment: Willkommen! Ich habe eine sehr ähnliche Frage auf Englisch hier gefunden: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15914/adjective-endings-after-a-noun-of-measurement/15915#15915