# x Jahre + Genitiv?

Tags: sentence-structure, genitive, declension, style, grammar-style

Bei so einer Ausformulierung wie **200 Jahre deutsche/r Einwanderung nach Brasilien** kann ich davon zwei synktaktische Möglichkeiten ableiten:

- Entweder *200 Jahre* wirkt als Attribut, das die Dauer der deutschen Einwanderung nach Brasilien näher bestimmt,
- oder es kann als Nomen stellvertretend für die Feier stehen, also das "200. Jubiläum" oder den "200. Jahrestag".

Liege ich hier bei der letzteren Deutung falsch und klingt diese Konstruktion einfach unüblich, auch in einem werbesprachigen Zusammenhang?

Beim Googeln nach Häufigkeit ergbibt sich, dass die erste Möglichkeit am verbreitesten ist, doch ich habe mich gefragt, ob es nicht eher eine Frage der Neuigkeit dieser bestimmten Wortwahl wäre, da die Feier erst dieses Jahr stattfindet. Deswegen wollte ich extrapolieren und nach grammatikalisch ähnlichen Konstruktionen suchen. Ich habe Titel wie *Fünf Jahre deutscher Kolonialpolitik* und *Zwanzig jahre deutscher Literatur* gefunden, denen ich auch eine Interpretation z.B. als *20 Jahr lange Zusammenstellung/Zeitleiste der deutschen Literatur* entnehme.

Meine Frage ist eigentlich folgende: Hören sich beide Möglichkeiten bei einem muttersprachlichen Ohr gut an?

Comment: Das letzte Beispiel klingt nicht so gut, das ist aber völlig unabhängig vom verwendeten Fall. Ich würde *eine 20 Jahre umfassende Zusammenstellung/Zeitleiste* schreiben, weil sich die Jahresangabe nicht auf die Zusammenstellung selbst bezieht.

Comment: 200 Jahre von etwas.

Answer (score 3):

Sowohl Nominativ als auch Genitiv sind "normal" und gängig. Der Genitiv wird typischerweise als gehobene Sprache betrachtet und ist normalerweise eher in geschriebenen Texten anzutreffen - In gesprochener Sprache wird man das sehr selten hören.

Die Genitivkonstruktion im Speziellen ist hier ein *genitivus quantitatis*, der einfach "eine Menge von etwas" ausdrückt. Es gibt also außer im "Anwendungsbereich" keinen Bedeutungsunterschied zu deinem ersten Beispiel.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15914/3237